# How can I represent highly fluctuating dataset of multiple signals without lowering actual signal?

Tags: r, dataset

I am looking for some good suggestions. I have highly fluctuating data from multiple samples (three samples are shown in light blue). When I calculate the mean (black line) of multiple samples, it appears that it reduces the high and low peak signals. Furthermore, Savitzky-Golay filtering (red color line) destroys the true high and low points of the mean (black line). So I'm wondering how I can represent such data while preserving the actual signals.

I'm working in R.

[image]

Data:

```
dat
    Location S1 S2 S3 Score         SG
1   43165001 -1 -3 -2  -2.0 -1.7571429
2   43165101 -1  1 -1  -0.2 -1.0114286
3   43165201 -2 -5  1  -1.6 -0.6228571
4   43165301  0  0 -1  -0.1 -0.8285714
5   43165401 -2  0  0  -1.0 -0.6742857
6   43165501  0 -2 -2  -1.1 -1.1171429
7   43165601 -2 -2  1  -1.0 -1.0771429
8   43165701 -1 -2 -2  -1.1 -0.9200000
9   43165801  1 -1 -2  -0.9 -1.4314286
10  43165901 -2 -3 -3  -2.0 -0.9457143
11  43166001  1  1  1   0.2 -0.9828571
12  43166101 -4 -3 -2  -2.0 -1.4514286
13  43166201  0 -3  0  -2.5 -2.2685714
14  43166301 -4 -1 -1  -1.6 -2.0457143
15  43166401  1 -1 -1  -2.3 -2.1542857
16  43166501 -8 -1  0  -2.4 -2.0400000
17  43166601  3 -5  0  -1.4 -2.1628571
18  43166701 -5 -6 -2  -3.0 -2.2371429
19  43166801 -2 -1  1  -2.0 -2.4114286
20  43166901 -4 -4 -4  -2.1 -2.1600000
21  43167001 -5 -3 -1  -2.2 -1.6942857
22  43167101  1 -1  0  -0.5 -1.1085714
23  43167201 -2 -2  0  -1.1 -0.6714286
24  43167301  0 -2 -2  -1.0 -1.5228571
25  43167401 -4 -1 -4  -2.2 -1.4028571
26  43167501  1 -2 -3  -0.6 -1.3457143
27  43167601 -5 -1  1  -1.4 -0.9200000
28  43167701 -1 -2 -1  -1.1 -1.3571429
29  43167801  0 -4 -3  -1.8 -1.8771429
30  43167901 -4 -2 -4  -2.6 -2.1971429
31  43168001  2 -1 -3  -1.7 -2.1714286
32  43168101 -5 -1  1  -2.0 -1.4942857
33  43168201  1 -1 -1  -0.9 -1.4742857
34  43168301 -4 -1 -2  -1.7 -1.2542857
35  43168401 -4  0  1  -1.0 -1.0685714
36  43168501 -1  0 -2  -0.6 -0.9942857
37  43168601 -3  0 -4  -1.5 -0.7285714
38  43168701  0  0  3  -0.1 -1.0857143
39  43168801 -1 -1 -4  -1.8 -0.7885714
40  43168901 -3  0  1  -0.5 -1.5200000
41  43169001 -1 -1 -2  -1.9 -0.7342857
42  43169101  2 -4  1   0.2 -1.0000000
43  43169201 -4  0 -2  -1.6 -0.6142857
44  43169301  0 -2  1  -0.7 -1.5314286
45  43169401 -6 -1 -2  -2.0 -1.2028571
46  43169501  1 -1 -1  -0.7 -1.3342857
47  43169601 -3 -1 -1  -1.3 -0.9142857
48  43169701 -2 -1 -2  -0.9 -1.2257143
49  43169801 -2 -1 -2  -1.1 -0.4914286
50  43169901  0  1  1   0.3 -0.6771429
51  43170001 -2 -6 -1  -1.6 -0.5885714
52  43170101  1  2 -2  -0.3 -1.0714286
53  43170201 -3 -2 -2  -1.1 -0.5085714
54  43170301  0 -1  0  -0.3 -0.8485714
55  43170401 -1 -2  0  -1.1 -0.5000000
56  43170501 -1 -1 -1  -0.3 -1.0800000
57  43170601 -5 -3 -1  -1.7 -0.7142857
58  43170701  2 -1  0   0.0 -0.9685714
59  43170801 -4 -1  0  -1.4 -0.7657143
60  43170901  0 -2  0  -0.8 -1.0400000
61  43171001 -1  1  0  -0.5 -0.2600000
62  43171101 -1 -2  0   0.0 -0.6514286
63  43171201  0 -4 -1  -1.6 -0.5714286
64  43171301 -1  3 -3   0.0 -1.0457143
65  43171401 -2 -6 -2  -1.9 -1.3514286
66  43171501 -4  0 -2  -1.8 -1.5428571
67  43171601  2 -2  0  -0.6 -1.4228571
68  43171701 -3 -2 -2  -2.2 -1.2742857
69  43171801 -2 -2 -2  -0.9 -1.6028571
70  43171901  1 -1 -1  -1.8 -1.4400000
71  43172001 -5 -2 -2  -1.8 -1.8514286
72  43172101  1 -3  1  -2.0 -2.3685714
73  43172201 -5  0 -5  -2.9 -2.0257143
74  43172301  1 -3  1  -0.7 -1.6685714
75  43172401 -3 -4 -2  -1.8 -1.1485714
76  43172501 -1 -2 -1  -1.3 -1.7457143
77  43172601 -4 -5 -1  -1.9 -1.5057143
78  43172701  0 -2 -1  -1.1 -1.3657143
79  43172801 -2 -1 -1  -1.0 -0.8542857
80  43172901  0  0  0  -0.6 -0.6942857
81  43173001 -1 -2 -1  -0.6 -0.5571429
82  43173101  1 -2  1  -0.6 -0.5828571
83  43173201 -2  1 -1  -0.7 -0.8542857
84  43173301 -2 -1 -2  -1.2 -0.8742857
85  43173401  0  0  0  -0.6 -0.9342857
86  43173501 -3 -1 -1  -1.2 -1.1485714
87  43173601 -2 -1 -1  -1.4 -1.0057143
88  43173701  1  1  1  -0.2 -0.7914286
89  43173801 -2 -1 -2  -1.2 -0.8571429
90  43173901  1 -2 -1  -1.1 -0.9885714
91  43174001 -1  0 -3  -0.6 -1.0800000
92  43174101  0 -2 -1  -1.7 -1.1085714
93  43174201 -1  1 -1  -0.8 -1.2800000
94  43174301 -1 -3 -2  -1.2 -0.8142857
95  43174401  0  2  0  -0.6 -0.9257143
96  43174501 -3 -3 -1  -1.2 -1.1485714
97  43174601 -3  1  0  -1.4 -0.9714286
98  43174701  2 -1 -2  -0.2 -1.0142857
99  43174801 -7 -1 -1  -1.6 -0.6485714
100 43174901  1  1 -2  -0.1 -0.9057143
101 43175001 -3 -1 -1  -1.3 -0.8800000
102 43175101 -1  0 -4  -1.4 -1.4085714
103 43175201 -2  0 -5  -1.5 -1.8171429
104 43175301 -3  0 -2  -2.6 -2.2057143
105 43175401  1 -3 -5  -2.0 -2.0942857
106 43175501 -5 -2 -2  -1.6 -1.8400000
107 43175601  4 -4 -1  -2.2 -1.8914286
108 43175701 -6  0  0  -1.8 -1.9628571
109 43175801  0 -4 -2  -2.0 -2.1371429
110 43175901 -3  2 -1  -2.5 -2.0285714
111 43176001 -1 -2  1  -1.4 -2.0171429
112 43176101 -3 -2 -2  -2.3 -1.7685714
113 43176201 -4  0 -2  -1.6 -1.9857143
114 43176301 -2 -3 -1  -1.9 -1.5742857
115 43176401 -2  0 -1  -1.3 -1.6342857
116 43176501 -1 -2 -1  -1.7 -1.3057143
117 43176601 -4 -1 -1  -1.1 -1.5628571
118 43176701 -4 -1 -1  -2.1 -1.8000000
119 43176801 -1 -1 -3  -1.9 -1.7628571
120 43176901 -2 -2  1  -1.2 -1.7400000
121 43177001 -1 -3 -1  -2.3 -1.7600000
122 43177101 -1  0  0  -1.2 -1.1742857
123 43177201  1  0  0  -0.2 -0.9200000
124 43177301 -1 -3 -1  -1.9 -0.9657143
125 43177401  0  0  1  -0.5 -1.1257143
126 43177501 -1 -1 -1  -1.1 -0.9885714
127 43177601  0 -1 -2  -1.5 -1.1657143
128 43177701 -3 -1  1  -0.8 -1.3485714
129 43177801 -1 -1 -4  -2.0 -1.6400000
130 43177901 -4 -5 -2  -1.7 -1.5714286
131 43178001  2 -1 -1  -0.7 -1.1457143
132 43178101 -3 -4  0  -1.3 -0.8714286
133 43178201 -2  0 -1  -0.6 -0.7800000
134 43178301  0 -3  1  -0.7 -0.9742857
135 43178401 -3 -2 -1  -1.6 -0.8885714
136 43178501  0  1  0  -0.1 -0.8971429
137 43178601 -2 -4  0  -1.3 -0.7685714
138 43178701 -2 -1  0  -1.0 -1.2228571
139 43178801 -2 -1 -3  -1.2 -1.2085714
140 43178901 -5 -2 -1  -1.3 -0.9314286
141 43179001  1  2 -1  -0.6 -1.5771429
142 43179101 -4 -5  0  -2.7 -1.1400000
143 43179201  1 -1  0   0.2 -1.5400000
144 43179301 -2 -1  0  -2.3 -0.7228571
145 43179401 -1 -3  0  -0.3 -1.6628571
146 43179501 -3 -1  0  -2.3 -1.1600000
147 43179601 -1 -1 -1  -0.9 -1.7657143
148 43179701 -4 -1 -1  -2.0 -1.4000000
149 43179801  2 -2 -3  -1.4 -1.5200000
150 43179901 -3 -1  1  -1.9 -1.9400000
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Location, y = Score)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = S1), color = "#6AA5F9", linetype=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S2), color = "#78ADF9", linetype=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S3), color = "#8DB5EF", linetype=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SG), color = "red", linetype=2) +
  ylab("Score")+
  xlab("Location")
```